# how to do calculations with qelement results in xml?

Tags: sql, xml

I have xml code that returns a result from an sql query:

```
<QElement FName = "Machine_DT" DBName="DB">
  declare @DT as int      
  set @DT =(SELECT TOP 1 [Value] FROM [DB].[dbo].[ConfigDBe] where [line] = '1' and [Name] = 'Hello')
  select isnull(@DT,0)
</QElement>
```

How can i use this result to perform calculations with it?

Comment: calculations such as Machine_DT + Machine_DT